# FormattedHtmlMessage react-intl v4

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatted-text

After upgrading to react-intl@4, we are facing a problem with all formattedHtmlMessages which have been used as html tag.

```
<FormattedHTMLMessage id={`${page}.legalNotice`} />
```

We tried replacing by formattedMessage and tried values={{...}}

```
<FormattedMessage id={`${page}.legalNotice`} />
```

But first of all the html is not considered as html tags.
Also as we use dynamic translation with different and undefined number of 'href's or even different 'target's on  tags(links) it does not seem to be the solution.

Our translations are something similar to this:

```
"myPage1.legalNotice" : "By clicking here I accept <a target="_self" title="my specific title" href='first_link.pdf'>LINK1</a>, and <a target="_blank" title="second_title" href='second_link'>LINK2</a> and <a target="_blank" href='third_link' title='third_title'>LINK3</a>."

"myPage2.legalNotice" : "Another Text .. <a target="_blank" href='another_link.pdf'>LINK2</a>."
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the Migration guide.
https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x

You have to provide the description for all the tags you use inside the message.

```
<FormattedMessage
  defaultMessage="To buy a shoe, <a>visit our website</a> and <cta>eat a shoe</cta>"
  values={{
    a: msg => (
      <a class="external_link" target="_blank" href="https://www.shoe.com/">
        {msg}
      </a>
    ),
    cta: msg => <strong class="important">{msg}</strong>,
  }}
/>
```

**Update: If you need to pass custom variables inside the variable**

Assuming you have `customHref` or `customTarget` variables defined:

```
a: msg => (
  <a class="external_link" target="${customTarget}" href="${customHref}">
    {msg}
  </a>
)
```

Comment: In my case <a> can have different href or target.

Comment: I second what @Noon said: The link can be part of the translation. How do I access the href of the mentioned link?

Comment: @Noon, you can configure what you are passing to href or target, as this is just a javascript variable at that point.
Example, assuming `customHref` and `customTarget` available in the context: 
```values={{
    a: msg => (
      <a class="external_link" target=`${customTarget}` href=`${customHref}`>
        {msg}
      </a>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep it the old way you can use such hack:

```
let message = intl.formatMessage({ id });
if (values) {
   Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        message = message.replace(`{${key}}`, value.toString());
    });
}
return(
    <span 
         dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formattedMessage }} 
    />
)
```